# How to call save method in collection instance

Tags: magento2, collection, save

I was appeared Magento 2 Associate developer certification exam, in that I got the below tricky question, but I don't know the concept and answer of the question. can you have an idea regarding the answer and concept means kindly share your thoughts?

```
What will be the result of calling the save() method on a collection instance?

1.  It will save all items with one INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    query. 
2.  It will save the select query to the cache.
3.  It will save the select query execution result into the cache. 
4.  It will loop over all items and call save() on each one.

What is the relationship between order entities and order address entities?

    1. One shipping address per unit of quantity is possible.
    2. One shipping address per line item is possible.
    3. Only one shipping address per order is possible
    4.  One shipping address per product type is possible.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my view, You can check below answer.

What will be the result of calling the save() method on a collection instance?

**Ans :** It will loop over all items and call save() on each one.

What is the relationship between order entities and order address entities?

**Ans :** Only one shipping address per order is possible

Comment: Thank for your answer, But for the second question, all the first 3 options are possible by the multishipping concept. then how did you marked option3 as an answer?

Comment: For second question, as per me "One shipping address per line item is possible." is the correct answer. Because if you enable multi-shopping, then each line item can be shipped on multiple address.

Comment: The correct answer is `One shipping address per unit of quantity is possible.`, here asking for the possibility of the Magento system.

Comment: @RakeshJakhar ,you are correct, "One shipping address per unit of quantity is possible" as I have checked the feature enabling multishipping.

Answer (score 2):

For (Q2), option (3) is correct, as even with multi shipping, once you place the order, magento creates separate order records, each having one single address.

Answer (score 0):

**According to Magento, The Correct Answers are as below -**

**Qes 1 :** *What will be the result of calling the `save()` method on a collection instance?*

**Ans 1 :** It will loop over all items and call `save()` on each one.

---

**Qes 2 :** *What is the relationship between order entities and order address entities?*

**Ans 2 :** `One shipping address per unit of quantity is possible.` (Check Multishipping feature is enabled or not)

Answer (score 0):

For the Second Question, option ***third*** would be the answer when you place order using Multishipping feature, Magento creates separate order records, each having one single address.

Please check below screen recording for more clarification -

https://nimb.ws/4vVzZn

https://nimb.ws/78R2sY

https://nimb.ws/170iNT